# Snowflake Invalid Identifier error while deleting data from snowsql cli

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-delete, delete-row, delete-operator

- I am trying to delete a record from a snowflake table using a sql script file through snowflake cli.
- For example from the table PIPELINE_CONFIG_DETAILS I want to delete the records where DAG_NAME = 'file_to_snowflake'
- And I want to make this as a generic one, so that the user can pass the table name and Filter condition as in input parameter to achieve the goal.
- For this I am passing the table name and where clause as the variables to the SQL file.
- The variable where clause is throwing me Invalid identifier error.
- I tried passing the variable values as DAG_NAME = 'file_to_snowflake' as well as DAG_NAME IN ('file_to_snowflake'), both values throwing the same error.

**Below is the command I am passing in the snowsql: with = in filter condition**
snowsql -c development -f sql_template_filter_parameter.sql -D SF_TABLE='"TestDb"."Dev"."PIPELINE_CONFIG_DETAILS"' -D SF_SQL_FILTER=DAG_NAME='file_to_snowflake'

**Below is the error I am getting: With = condition**
000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 75
invalid identifier '"DAG_NAME='file_to_snowflake'"'

**Below is the command I am passing in the snowsql: with *IN* in the filter condition**
snowsql -c development -f sql_template_filter_parameter.sql -D SF_TABLE='"SANDPIT"."MCM_SANDBOX"."PIPELINE_CONFIG_DETAILS_3_COLS"' -D SF_SQL_FILTER="DAG_NAME"\ IN('file_to_snowflake') -o remove_comments=tru
e

**Below is the error I am getting: With *IN* condition**
000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 75
invalid identifier '"DAG_NAME IN('file_to_snowflake')"'

**Below is the body content of the SQL file.**
!SET variable_substitution=true;

DELETE FROM "&{SF_TABLE}" WHERE "&{SF_SQL_FILTER}";

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "&{SF_TABLE}";

Hope I am clear with the use case.

Any little help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Raghu.

Answer (score 0):

Your -D parameter is wrong:

-D SF_SQL_FILTER=DAG_NAME='file_to_snowflake'

You have 3 values and 2 = signs, which makes no sense

Comment: Thanks @NickW , Logically that makes sense, but the error seems to be related to SFSQL , nothing to do with SnowSQL CLI. That's where I am confused with the error message.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the where clause as an argument? If it is a single column and single value, then we can achieve it with two parameters Field and Value. But that approach doesn't work if there are multiple fields and / or multiple values to be passed. Thanks in Advance, Raghu.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to explain, with examples, what it is you are trying to do? What is the actual sql you are trying to run on Snowflake and what are the contents of the various files you are including in the command line

Comment: Hi @NickW, I am trying to delete specific records from given table using a sql script file. 
For example from PIPELINE_CONFIG_DETAILS table I want to delete records with DAG_NAME = 'file_to_snowflake'. And I want to pass the Table name and Filter condition as input parameters so that user can pass any table and any filter criterion to delete the records. Below is my SQL Script.

 !SET variable_substitution=true;

DELETE FROM "&{SF_TABLE}" WHERE "&{SF_SQL_FILTER}";

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "&{SF_TABLE}";

select working as expected. Delete not working even with IN clause.
Hope I am clear